# More than one conditional compilation symbols?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, project-properties

I have a question regarding conditional compilation symbols in Visual Studio (my version is 2017).

Assuming that I have two compilation symbols, e. g.:

```
#if new_version
#if old_version
```

then in what typing should I put them in Project properties ->Build ->Conditional compilations symbols:

1) `new_version, old_version`

2) `new_version;old_version`

3) `new_version; old_version`

4) `new_version,old_version`

5) other options?

Any suggestion which way is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use semi-colons, but I would think with names like new_version and old_version that you would generally only define one of them.